# How to secure socket.io using Nodejs and Flutter

Tags: node.js, flutter, socket.io

I developed app using Nodejs and Flutter with socket.io client. I want to secure the Socket.io during the communication between two users. Any guide or suggestion pls? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Flutter, you can an extra header to your option headers.
`'extraHeaders': {HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: '$accessToken'}`

```
import 'package:socket_io_client/socket_io_client.dart' as IO;

IO.Socket createSocket(String accessToken) {
  final url = 'https://$yourDomainHere';
  return IO.io(url,
    <String, dynamic>{
      'transports': ['websocket'],
      'rejectUnauthorized': false,
      'autoConnect': false,
      'extraHeaders': {HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: '$accessToken'}
    });
}
```

Comment: Great thanks . So I can use jwt to verify that token in node.js right?

Comment: Yes, you should be able to. @LeslieJoe